# Using Prototypes Over Classes In JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Is there a reason to use prototypes over classes? If I understand correctly, prototypes would be more efficient if I had defined functions in the constructor (but that is not the case here). Is the only thing different between these implementations syntax?

```
    class Quiz {
    constructor(questions) {
        this.score = 0;
        this.questionArray = questions;
        this.questionIndex = 0;
    }

    getCurrentQuestionObj() {
        return this.questionArray[this.questionIndex];
    }

    isGameOver() {
        return this.questionArray.length === this.questionIndex;
    }

    guess(answer) {
        if(this.getCurrentQuestionObj().isCorrectAnswer(answer)) {
            this.score++;
        }
        this.questionIndex++;
    }
}
```

-

```
function Quiz(questions) {
    this.score = 0;
    this.questions = questions;
    this.questionIndex = 0;
}

Quiz.prototype.getCurrentQuestionObj = function() {
    return this.questions[this.questionIndex];
}

Quiz.prototype.isGameOver = function() {
    return this.questions.length === this.questionIndex;
}

Quiz.prototype.guess = function(answer) {
    if(this.getCurrentQuestionObj().correctAnswer(answer)) {
        this.score++;
    }
    this.questionIndex++;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

ES6 classes are nothing more than sugar.  Your two examples are equivalent.

Regarding functions declared in the constructor - you're right that those would be slightly less efficient.  If you set 'this.foo = function() {}' in the constructor a new function is created every time you instantiate using the constructor.

Comment: But when using a `prototype` you can broader the class definition, while `class` notation is not so easily expandable.

Comment: @john_omalley Is there any downsides of using classes? I know it's a more recent feature that came with ES6, but I don't see it used too often.

Comment: The only downside I can think of is that you need to transpile them to work in older browsers.

Comment: re: 'class notation is not so easily expandable'... not sure what you mean but it's really 100% equivalent.  try it out in Node or Chrome.

Comment: I understand using prototype would allow me to expand on the second implementation, but how would I expand on the class definition?

Comment: class SubClass extends SuperClass {...}

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes

Comment: Got it. I wasn't sure there was any other way other besides making a subclass.